# Strawberry perl and pp file extension

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

Could Someone explain what are the .pp files on strawberry perl directory ,

for example i have the following file 64bit-5.16.0.1.pp and many other files with this extension .

what this extension means (.pp)  are those the builds of strawberry and if yes can i build some .pp file of my own with my extra modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`64bit-5.16.0.1.pp` file is part of [Perl::Dist::Strawberry](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl%3a%3aDist%3a%3aStrawberry) which is used to build [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com) distribution (it is not part of standard strawberry installation, you have to install it via `cpan` or `cpanm` command).

The `*.pp` files are in fact a build configuration defining what components are bundled into strawberry perl distribution.

You can create a modified version of any `*.pp` file (see [examples](https://metacpan.org/source/KMX/Perl-Dist-Strawberry-3.012/share)) and create your own strawberry-like perl distribution. Just install [Perl::Dist::Strawberry](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl%3a%3aDist%3a%3aStrawberry) and use `perldist_strawberry` command with proper parameters - see [perldist_strawberry usage](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldist_strawberry)

Answer (score 0):

.pp could be for "Pure Perl"? There are cases where a module comes in several implementations, like an XS module and a pure perl module. If so, there might be a difference in speed, where a XS tends to be faster.